# gradle parallel exec commandline

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, parallel-processing

we've got a gradle project that compiles cobol to java. This is happening via a batch file that is called with a parameter (filename) from a gradle task:

```
def compileSingleFile(String cblFileName) {
    exec {
        commandLine "${projectDir}/compileFile.bat"
        args "${cblFileName}"
        ignoreExitValue = true
    }
}
```

Currently, we iterate through a list of files, every file is compiled after another:

```
task ciBuild {
    dependsOn collectFiles
    doLast {
        cobolfiles.parallelStream().each {file ->
            if(file.toUpperCase().endsWith("CBL")) {
                compileSingleFile(file)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there a possibility in gradle to run this task in a kind of ... a thread pool? For example 10 threads each one compiling another file? Untill the list is empty?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks run sequentially and should never be explicitly invoked by your code. There's nothing stopping you from running [project.exec(Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec(groovy.lang.Closure)) in a `doLast { }`

Eg:

```
task ciBuild {
    def cobolFiles = fileTree("src/main/cobol").matching {
        include "**/*.CBL"
    }
    dependsOn collectFiles
    inputs.files cobolFiles
    outputs.dir 'path/to/outputDir'
    doLast {
        cobolFiles.files.parallelStream().each { File file ->
            exec {
                commandLine "${projectDir}/compileFile.bat"
                args file.absolutePath
                ignoreExitValue = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to set something like "maxParallelForks" or something?

Comment: I personally don't like `parallelStream()` as I don't have control over the thread pool. You'd likely use [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) and a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) if you wanted full control